# Prove that d and d' are not strongly equivalent.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $d$ be the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $d'$ be another metric defined by $d'(x, y) = min(1, d(x, y))$. Prove that $d$ and $d'$ are not strongly equivalent.

In the solution that we get it says:
Note that the open ball $B_{d'}(x,3/2)=\mathbb{R}$. Thus the metrics can't be strongly equivalent.

I'm just wondering how $B_{d'}(x,3/2)=\mathbb{R}$ is true, can someone please explain how you get that?

Comment: Well, $d'(x,y)≤1$ for all $x,y$ so every $y\in \mathbb R$ is in that ball.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thank you. Do you know if strong equivalence can be defined in terms of open balls?

Comment: What is ‘strong equivalence’ ?

Comment: @MPW I am not sure what is meant either.  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162359/an-equivalence-relation-for-norms) is one use of the term but I have no idea if that is what is meant here.  In my comment I was only addressing the question: "Why is $B_{d'}\left(x, \frac 32\right)=\mathbb R$."

Comment: It’s just because every point is within $3/2$ units of every other point in this metric. No two points are further than $1$ unit apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two metrics $d$ and $d'$ on a set $X$ are strongly equivalent iff there are constants $C,D>0$ such that

$$\forall x,y \in X: C\cdot d(x,y) \le d'(x,y) \le D\cdot d(x,y)$$

First $d'(x,y)=\min((d(x,y), 1) \le 1$ so that indeed $B_{d'}(x, \frac{3}{2})=\Bbb R$ simply because $1 < \frac32$ and the definition of the open ball.

Now note that if $C,D$ existed as above, then take $x=0, y=n$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$ and note that $C\cdot d(x,y) = nC$ while $1 = d'(0,n)$ for all $n$, so for large enough $n$, the inequality won't hold.

Alternatively, note that the inequalities imply: $B_{d'}(x,r) \subseteq B_d(x, \frac{r}{C})$ for all $x$ and $r>0$ and taking any $x$ and $r=\frac{3}{2}$ refutes that, as we saw.